# Bootstrap (or custom CSS) multilevel div layout

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I apologies for perhaps asking the wrong question, but I have searched and not found anything similar to help me phrase my question better. I have an array of objects, each has three layers. I would like to display the different layers in different rows. It is quite difficult to explain so I will resort in giving some dummy data and drawing the result I would like to achieve.

```
[{
  name:Bloem High, 
  type:High School, 
  teacher:[
    { 
      name:Sam, 
      discipline:Math, 
      students:[
        {
          name:Ben,
          grade: A+
        },
        {
          name:Zoe,
          grade:B-
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name:Pete,
      discipline:Science,
      students:[
        {
          name:Hymne,
          grade: A+
        },
        {
          name: Pierre,
          grade: A-
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

So the above is an example of lets say one of many schools. now I would like to display the multiple schools as follow.

First a row of School Names as a little card, below each school a row of teacher of that school and below each teacher a column of students. Please see the dodgy picture for a better explanation. Also I would like everything to be in div that scrol horizontal.

[Graphical explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3L9H.jpg)

[another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBGSq.jpg)

I will appreciate any and all help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a table, so I suggest using [tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Does this help? I'm not sure if I'm answering the right question

Comment: Thank you @Dotan. I considered tables. But I am not sure how to achieve the desired result with them. My problem is that the amount of teachers will influence the columns width. Would you perhaps be able to show how you would achieve it in a table dynamically?

Comment: @MariusRossouw you can set the column width manually, with e.g. `td {width: 33%; }`

Comment: Thank you @Dotan but I think I am not making myself clear. I would like to build the table dynamically and there will be blank cells with no data in and I do not know how to do that with ng-repeat or a table. In the image that I supplied you will see that there are two or three teacher for each school and multiple learners per teacher. Ill add another image.